# Xamarin IOS Release build crashing on the device but works fine on simulator

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios, xamarin.forms, release, xamarin-studio

Earlier I used to create release build .ipa file by selecting Release and Device option beside the play button from Xamarin Studio. With recent update of Xamarin Studio I don't see the option of device next to release / debug but rather I see "generic device" as option.

The debug mode works fine on both simulator and device. But in the release mode it works fine on simulator but on actual device the app opens and then closes back in fraction of second ( possibly crashing ).
I gave an adhoc release app by signing with my keys to my client, earlier it used to work fine but the same issue is being faced by them on their iPad after the Xamarin Studio update .

Tried reinstalling my provisional certificates, but nothing changed. Issue still persist.

The logs:

```
Incident Identifier: 62FB5B4C-133D-42DF-B2F6-200C87D09401
CrashReporter Key:   8fa5287d205eccdce7c687bbd797bd4643c7c10e
Hardware Model:      iPhone9,3
Process:             LoginPage.iOS [565]
Path:                /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/86DEFD11-8152-4A45-AB55-AB8679C30CAF/LoginPage.iOS.app/LoginPage.iOS
Identifier:          com.xxx.xxxxx
Version:             1.0 (1.0)
Code Type:           ARM-64 (Native)
Role:                Foreground
Parent Process:      launchd [1]
Coalition:           com.xxxxxx.xxxxx [641]


Date/Time:           2017-06-20 01:17:05.6561 +0530
Launch Time:         2017-06-20 01:17:05.6124 +0530
OS Version:          iPhone OS 10.3.2 (14F89)
Report Version:      104

Exception Type:  EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT)
Exception Codes: 0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000
Exception Note:  EXC_CORPSE_NOTIFY
Triggered by Thread:  0

Application Specific Information:
abort() called

Filtered syslog:
None found

Thread 0 name:  tid_403  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
Thread 0 Crashed:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x0000000187671014 __pthread_kill + 8
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000018773b264 pthread_kill + 112
2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x00000001875e59c4 abort + 140
3   LoginPage.iOS                   0x000000010101ac1c 0x100014000 + 16804892
4   libsystem_platform.dylib        0x000000018773531c _sigtramp + 52
5   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000018773b264 pthread_kill + 112
6   libsystem_c.dylib               0x00000001875e59c4 abort + 140
7   LoginPage.iOS                   0x0000000101106010 0x100014000 + 17768464
8   LoginPage.iOS                   0x0000000101115080 0x100014000 + 17830016
9   LoginPage.iOS                   0x0000000100fea828 0x100014000 + 16607272
10  LoginPage.iOS                   0x0000000101034c20 0x100014000 + 16911392
11  LoginPage.iOS                   0x0000000101034780 0x100014000 + 16910208
12  LoginPage.iOS                   0x000000010111e188 0x100014000 + 17867144
13  LoginPage.iOS                   0x0000000101036768 0x100014000 + 16918376
14  LoginPage.iOS                   0x000000010105342c 0x100014000 + 17036332
15  LoginPage.iOS                   0x0000000101025ccc 0x100014000 + 16850124
16  LoginPage.iOS                   0x000000010111dea4 0x100014000 + 17866404
17  LoginPage.iOS                   0x0000000100fe9684 0x100014000 + 16602756
18  libdyld.dylib                   0x000000018756159c start + 4

Thread 1:
0   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000187736ca8 start_wqthread + 0

Thread 2:
0   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000187736ca8 start_wqthread + 0

Thread 3:
0   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000187736ca8 start_wqthread + 0

Thread 4:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x0000000187670e1c __psynch_cvwait + 8
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000187738814 _pthread_cond_wait + 640
2   libc++.1.dylib                  0x0000000187061ac8 std::__1::condition_variable::wait(std::__1::unique_lock<std::__1::mutex>&) + 56
3   JavaScriptCore                  0x000000018cf05f94 void std::__1::condition_variable_any::wait<std::__1::unique_lock<bmalloc::Mutex> >(std::__1::unique_lock<bmalloc::Mutex>&) + 112
4   JavaScriptCore                  0x000000018cf05f08 bmalloc::AsyncTask<bmalloc::Heap, void (bmalloc::Heap::*)()>::threadRunLoop() + 168
5   JavaScriptCore                  0x000000018cf05de8 std::__1::__shared_ptr_emplace<std::__1::mutex, std::__1::allocator<std::__1::mutex> >::~__shared_ptr_emplace() + 0
6   JavaScriptCore                  0x000000018cf06098 void* std::__1::__thread_proxy<std::__1::tuple<void (*)(bmalloc::AsyncTask<bmalloc::Heap, void (bmalloc::Heap::*)()>*), bmalloc::AsyncTask<bmalloc::Heap, void (bmalloc::Heap::*)()>*> >(void*) + 92
7   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000018773968c _pthread_body + 240
8   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000018773959c _pthread_body + 0
9   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000187736cb4 thread_start + 4

Thread 5 name:  WebThread
Thread 5:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x0000000187653224 mach_msg_trap + 8
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x000000018765309c mach_msg + 72
2   CoreFoundation                  0x0000000188624e90 __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 192
3   CoreFoundation                  0x0000000188622ae4 __CFRunLoopRun + 1060
4   CoreFoundation                  0x0000000188552da4 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 424
5   WebCore                         0x000000018d224608 RunWebThread(void*) + 456
6   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000018773968c _pthread_body + 240
7   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000018773959c _pthread_body + 0
8   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000187736cb4 thread_start + 4

Thread 6:
0   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000187736cb0 thread_start + 0

Thread 0 crashed with ARM Thread State (64-bit):
    x0: 0x0000000000000000   x1: 0x0000000000000000   x2: 0x0000000000000000   x3: 0x0000000000000020
    x4: 0x000000000000001b   x5: 0x0000000000000014   x6: 0x0000000000000000   x7: 0x00000000000009d0
    x8: 0x0000000008000000   x9: 0x0000000004000000  x10: 0x0000000000000000  x11: 0x0000000000003fff
   x12: 0x0000000101500000  x13: 0x000000000000268e  x14: 0x0000000040000000  x15: 0x000000000000268e
   x16: 0x0000000000000148  x17: 0x0000000100000000  x18: 0x0000000000000000  x19: 0x0000000000000006
   x20: 0x00000001ae7d8b40  x21: 0x00000001011b4341  x22: 0x00000001011b4391  x23: 0x000000016fde96c8
   x24: 0x0000000000000000  x25: 0x000000010200f280  x26: 0x0000000000000000  x27: 0x00000001011ec5b8
   x28: 0x00000001011ea178   fp: 0x000000016fde9660   lr: 0x000000018773b264
    sp: 0x000000016fde9640   pc: 0x0000000187671014 cpsr: 0x00000000

Binary Images:
0x100014000 - 0x1011d7fff LoginPage.iOS arm64  <6e5958991b983bc3976cc817deddc795> /var/containers/Bundle/Application/86DEFD11-8152-4A45-AB55-AB8679C30CAF/LoginPage.iOS.app/LoginPage.iOS
0x1013e4000 - 0x101417fff dyld arm64  <a3339f99c2ea39d8beb70b8ff2e84061> /usr/lib/dyld
0x187058000 - 0x187059fff libSystem.B.dylib arm64  <2e9654eb84903bd7aee0815fd9d27591> /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib
0x18705a000 - 0x1870affff libc++.1.dylib arm64  <da0f6a86db853140b2d79e3b36f28795> /usr/lib/libc++.1.dylib
0x1870b0000 - 0x1870ccfff libc++abi.dylib arm64  <5dc5ba28cfa43f838099049d17ba9ec6> /usr/lib/libc++abi.dylib
0x1870d0000 - 0x1874adfff libobjc.A.dylib arm64  <85f3b59b96243690b138ce96e663bf4b> /usr/lib/libobjc.A.dylib
0x1874ae000 - 0x1874b2fff libcache.dylib arm64  <5d1024035c983afdacc90dad2f0280ec> /usr/lib/system/libcache.dylib
0x1874b3000 - 0x1874befff libcommonCrypto.dylib arm64  <0ca00f1d89553b9e8ad032310e8ecbb8> /usr/lib/system/libcommonCrypto.dylib
0x1874bf000 - 0x1874c2fff libcompiler_rt.dylib arm64  <771427d857db3158b2f7d971afa219c9> /usr/lib/system/libcompiler_rt.dylib
0x1874c3000 - 0x1874cafff libcopyfile.dylib arm64  <793e7046ae7c3b65b17d6e0d9fe975fd> /usr/lib/system/libcopyfile.dylib
0x1874cb000 - 0x18752cfff libcorecrypto.dylib arm64  <66d47f7529873633892967a26e598456> /usr/lib/system/libcorecrypto.dylib
0x18752d000 - 0x18755cfff libdispatch.dylib arm64  <1643bcf57daf389784dfcad8c485fd3e> /usr/lib/system/libdispatch.dylib
0x18755d000 - 0x187561fff libdyld.dylib arm64  <6c6a61f720cf30daa4a357cbefbf4cd6> /usr/lib/system/libdyld.dylib
0x187562000 - 0x187562fff liblaunch.dylib arm64  <1539b0564b4b34f78ab27c96400c3619> /usr/lib/system/liblaunch.dylib
0x187563000 - 0x187568fff libmacho.dylib arm64  <9434199c06b73b7090f38d0d0f6e6c20> /usr/lib/system/libmacho.dylib
0x187569000 - 0x18756afff libremovefile.dylib arm64  <2262f08800e630af981ed21f7240d32e> /usr/lib/system/libremovefile.dylib
0x18756b000 - 0x187582fff libsystem_asl.dylib arm64  <8c876d02afeb3aa18e733bbdbfa074f9> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_asl.dylib
0x187583000 - 0x187583fff libsystem_blocks.dylib arm64  <45adbecbe4b93744911aa6314fbbc8ff> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_blocks.dylib
0x187584000 - 0x187600fff libsystem_c.dylib arm64  <31008bfe57f7313a974fad1f76e24496> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_c.dylib
0x187601000 - 0x187605fff libsystem_configuration.dylib arm64  <99e65007dcd2368da0a7896f491ece18> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_configuration.dylib
0x187606000 - 0x18760bfff libsystem_containermanager.dylib arm64  <62636c63790b3c0d9cc115fc73d66ba2> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_containermanager.dylib
0x18760c000 - 0x18760dfff libsystem_coreservices.dylib arm64  <9eec7dc8a2d831639eaf9bd9b3e70377> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_coreservices.dylib
0x18760e000 - 0x187626fff libsystem_coretls.dylib arm64  <f7a5e11e082d37babe31812e9717fcf0> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_coretls.dylib
0x187627000 - 0x18762dfff libsystem_dnssd.dylib arm64  <9700821f537737e4b2f91607acb78aa7> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_dnssd.dylib
0x18762e000 - 0x187651fff libsystem_info.dylib arm64  <077e4a85b19f3b00b768a5eb34fe46b5> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_info.dylib
0x187652000 - 0x187676fff libsystem_kernel.dylib arm64  <275624061b1a3ab391baf08b4ba58a97> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_kernel.dylib
0x187677000 - 0x1876a3fff libsystem_m.dylib arm64  <d8e9248df4523f35a7ac365dab827fba> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_m.dylib
0x1876a4000 - 0x1876bffff libsystem_malloc.dylib arm64  <56104290e798374188ef0da981dc3146> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_malloc.dylib
0x1876c0000 - 0x187719fff libsystem_network.dylib arm64  <54ba9caf24023fd0ad569557ac08b1a6> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_network.dylib
0x18771a000 - 0x187723fff libsystem_networkextension.dylib arm64  <8aef40a6317b3062b40dc94d87f7d1bf> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_networkextension.dylib
0x187724000 - 0x18772efff libsystem_notify.dylib arm64  <1da4fe88c1ad31b6a5c7c2138f5d1c94> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_notify.dylib
0x18772f000 - 0x187735fff libsystem_platform.dylib arm64  <a0a582b8f653379e8ac7799e83c90b1f> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_platform.dylib
0x187736000 - 0x18773ffff libsystem_pthread.dylib arm64  <8f14c41e6536348a9b6ffd2a82be7d57> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_pthread.dylib
0x187740000 - 0x187743fff libsystem_sandbox.dylib arm64  <ac550550955c37c2b2e4022095b4b8de> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_sandbox.dylib
0x187744000 - 0x18774bfff libsystem_symptoms.dylib arm64  <39c51c9bffa030ef82de6c281436e836> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_symptoms.dylib
0x18774c000 - 0x18775efff libsystem_trace.dylib arm64  <3fdd15d2b2c33d68b8cc600d0482b5fd> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_trace.dylib
0x18775f000 - 0x187764fff libunwind.dylib arm64  <990bab05c7b333f3bfc274d5ea579b71> /usr/lib/system/libunwind.dylib
0x187765000 - 0x187765fff libvminterpose.dylib arm64  <dabe83c40ec235dfb7f0e8fe395e1844> /usr/lib/system/libvminterpose.dylib
0x187766000 - 0x18778cfff libxpc.dylib arm64  <7a12d1ee49b73e1eb582b9c359c7fe79> /usr/lib/system/libxpc.dylib
0x18778d000 - 0x1879a2fff libicucore.A.dylib arm64  <d7b181cad9a438e7b6e010c2e4c8da5e> /usr/lib/libicucore.A.dylib
0x1879a3000 - 0x1879b4fff libz.1.dylib arm64  <ab0d683d7cf931e49e5456a420ced72e> /usr/lib/libz.1.dylib
0x18854a000 - 0x1888cbfff CoreFoundation arm64  <719044f95fe23ee0ab14504def42b100> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/CoreFoundation
0x1888cc000 - 0x1888dcfff libbsm.0.dylib arm64  <4f2930cfb67e3965a863f8bfb7704300> /usr/lib/libbsm.0.dylib
0x1888dd000 - 0x1888ddfff libenergytrace.dylib arm64  <5cfceffa0be736398124efbb3d80cbd1> /usr/lib/libenergytrace.dylib
0x1888de000 - 0x188959fff IOKit arm64  <6f72fc6ac9d2309dbf33c8b014c129d0> /System/Library/Frameworks/IOKit.framework/Versions/A/IOKit
0x18895a000 - 0x18897afff libMobileGestalt.dylib arm64  <5674397d74c33492a16f51f6fd33f114> /usr/lib/libMobileGestalt.dylib
0x18897b000 - 0x188a64fff libxml2.2.dylib arm64  <605bee9eb5ff3c43a65d251460f3650c> /usr/lib/libxml2.2.dylib
0x188a65000 - 0x188afffff Security arm64  <287bf21cb54734b9b91574ccb4e71436> /System/Library/Frameworks/Security.framework/Security
0x188b00000 - 0x188b6bfff SystemConfiguration arm64  <57d2eead9fcf34ecaa81c225ad8345e1> /System/Library/Frameworks/SystemConfiguration.framework/SystemConfiguration
0x188b6c000 - 0x188c7cfff libsqlite3.dylib arm64  <aa3a5cd643b43e40b5680d5a3758ab8f> /usr/lib/libsqlite3.dylib
0x188c7d000 - 0x188ff1fff CFNetwork arm64  <05331a42dd8b31cea6ef547eadc487cd> /System/Library/Frameworks/CFNetwork.framework/CFNetwork
0x188ff2000 - 0x188ffffff libbz2.1.0.dylib arm64  <29e1c06129583bb5b423bbfd7397c0e5> /usr/lib/libbz2.1.0.dylib
0x189000000 - 0x189018fff liblzma.5.dylib arm64  <eb9e235443573c948bcd016ea00a3709> /usr/lib/liblzma.5.dylib
0x189019000 - 0x189033fff libCRFSuite.dylib arm64  <a859d30f7de034a2bee5aa662bc5bc2d> /usr/lib/libCRFSuite.dylib
0x189034000 - 0x18905dfff libarchive.2.dylib arm64  <a31887c5b46a3b97ad308f4db869be43> /usr/lib/libarchive.2.dylib
0x18905e000 - 0x18905ffff liblangid.dylib arm64  <80d66702d7ce30b7b75c3f75472697eb> /usr/lib/liblangid.dylib
0x189060000 - 0x18932ffff Foundation arm64  <08e6a29fdbac38dd817c66cedf0e0052> /System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Foundation
0x189330000 - 0x1893dbfff libBLAS.dylib arm64  <708d8599265c39d3881fc57c55bc982d> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/libBLAS.dylib
0x1893dc000 - 0x18970afff libLAPACK.dylib arm64  <96e5ce2234903263ad30c6398972d535> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/libLAPACK.dylib
0x18970b000 - 0x1899a5fff vImage arm64  <1f67094759de381898830a3692edff0f> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vImage.framework/vImage
0x1899a6000 - 0x1899cbfff libvMisc.dylib arm64  <3de044e80d883d6188e8ce8a8572ec5b> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/libvMisc.dylib
0x1899cc000 - 0x1899e0fff libLinearAlgebra.dylib arm64  <37c71c692da03cc9a1534badab1cf6f4> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/libLinearAlgebra.dylib
0x1899e1000 - 0x1899f2fff libSparseBLAS.dylib arm64  <2237c532ebe539f8ab93c181dfa1a291> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/libSparseBLAS.dylib
0x1899f3000 - 0x189a68fff libvDSP.dylib arm64  <0ced33b1008e357e9acb9d039cff697d> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/libvDSP.dylib
0x189a69000 - 0x189a69fff vecLib arm64  <d21c98b0003235f99d247f4f934c7641> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/vecLib
0x189a6a000 - 0x189a6afff Accelerate arm64  <f38de9acd0ba3a00a1c32fda7a240f38> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Accelerate
0x189a6b000 - 0x189faffff CoreGraphics arm64  <7d39f265eae8328f801705549c70e571> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreGraphics.framework/CoreGraphics
0x189fb0000 - 0x189fc4fff GraphicsServices arm64  <b5749f3fa6f13ce689683db33f23256c> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/GraphicsServices.framework/GraphicsServices
0x189fc5000 - 0x18a012fff AppSupport arm64  <2a60ffa70fa13031a1251b964802ad31> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AppSupport.framework/AppSupport
0x18a013000 - 0x18a140fff MobileCoreServices arm64  <78cfd6fb54fa3b2abaa4006791ac96ca> /System/Library/Frameworks/MobileCoreServices.framework/MobileCoreServices
0x18a141000 - 0x18a1a2fff BaseBoard arm64  <ff0febbec86337aead2c18f8ac460dec> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/BaseBoard.framework/BaseBoard
0x18a1a3000 - 0x18a1b2fff AssertionServices arm64  <8ff92082f5833b7795af4a2200886ce2> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AssertionServices.framework/AssertionServices
0x18a1b3000 - 0x18a1e0fff BackBoardServices arm64  <7bd5622615bb39cdba684e47e9bb8798> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/BackBoardServices.framework/BackBoardServices
0x18a1e5000 - 0x18a234fff FrontBoardServices arm64  <6adf5e0649313e35bd11d448eb071d17> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/FrontBoardServices.framework/FrontBoardServices
0x18a238000 - 0x18a26cfff SpringBoardServices arm64  <a5f42cadcaba3943953f5047533c2fe7> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/SpringBoardServices.framework/SpringBoardServices
0x18a26d000 - 0x18a287fff MobileKeyBag arm64  <51a5be975d3a37c2af8751a5b9124948> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MobileKeyBag.framework/MobileKeyBag
0x18a288000 - 0x18a290fff IOSurface arm64  <acecdca025ff36b4b14159e52e2819dd> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/IOSurface.framework/IOSurface
0x18a291000 - 0x18a29cfff liblockdown.dylib arm64  <3904292ecd513a0e85216e7c3abd1101> /usr/lib/liblockdown.dylib
0x18a29d000 - 0x18a2b3fff CrashReporterSupport arm64  <b06bf5fa4c9b36f595a2a8ea4a84cca9> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CrashReporterSupport.framework/CrashReporterSupport
0x18a2b4000 - 0x18a2b6fff IOSurfaceAccelerator arm64  <7dd37fd295f93ecfa89401bbbb418dbf> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/IOSurfaceAccelerator.framework/IOSurfaceAccelerator
0x18a2b7000 - 0x18a2f7fff AppleJPEG arm64  <d8b98c13f8d83200ad41d6b30d3c9c14> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AppleJPEG.framework/AppleJPEG
0x18a2f8000 - 0x18a885fff ImageIO arm64  <9133dcebff4c3ab6807f96f884190cb5> /System/Library/Frameworks/ImageIO.framework/ImageIO
0x18a886000 - 0x18a88cfff TCC arm64  <b11f764c841d3c69a50a6b0993735d43> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/TCC.framework/TCC
0x18a88d000 - 0x18a891fff AggregateDictionary arm64  <fab7b20283e43d8aa268b7d051e3d521> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AggregateDictionary.framework/AggregateDictionary
0x18a892000 - 0x18a89efff PowerLog arm64  <a668cd2a3ad03c0291a9665f3151f946> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/PowerLog.framework/PowerLog
0x18a89f000 - 0x18a909fff libTelephonyUtilDynamic.dylib arm64  <a9cba41bffa83838b49c3f8ff2538f8a> /usr/lib/libTelephonyUtilDynamic.dylib
0x18a90a000 - 0x18a91cfff CommonUtilities arm64  <495171d174123535af0ff1751ef454b3> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CommonUtilities.framework/CommonUtilities
0x18a91d000 - 0x18a932fff libcompression.dylib arm64  <c5e41b4a6cbf37fb87cd5cd44f6906b8> /usr/lib/libcompression.dylib
0x18a933000 - 0x18abcbfff CoreData arm64  <7574c4fafa7a33bf82e05d9fa01ed542> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreData.framework/CoreData
0x18abcc000 - 0x18abd1fff libCoreVMClient.dylib arm64  <07e215340c3239fea6c469df55183bcd> /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGLES.framework/libCoreVMClient.dylib
0x18abd2000 - 0x18abd7fff IOAccelerator arm64  <54e24860953b39ddbe13a2dcdf76c733> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/IOAccelerator.framework/IOAccelerator
0x18abd8000 - 0x18abd9fff libCVMSPluginSupport.dylib arm64  <02280e05346d31509d62ac2583f72857> /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGLES.framework/libCVMSPluginSupport.dylib
0x18abda000 - 0x18abddfff libCoreFSCache.dylib arm64  <f5c0306167ea39b2b60185329c1a8bbb> /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGLES.framework/libCoreFSCache.dylib
0x18abde000 - 0x18ac1ffff libGLImage.dylib arm64  <34bb7e96428f3c1abd6f0cbb2787b9e1> /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGLES.framework/libGLImage.dylib
0x18ac20000 - 0x18ac2afff libGFXShared.dylib arm64  <d70b4c465ebe3a9e98c2b82ccf8fb7d7> /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGLES.framework/libGFXShared.dylib
0x18ac2b000 - 0x18ac33fff IOMobileFramebuffer arm64  /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGLES.framework/OpenGLES
0x18aca2000 - 0x18acc6fff CoreVideo arm64  <ba0cdc15666b32f7be6f9fcd1528c7f1> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreVideo.framework/CoreVideo
0x18acc7000 - 0x18acc9fff OAuth arm64  <56d873bb47973452a9fc41ee777f8d42> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/OAuth.framework/OAuth
0x18acd1000 - 0x18ad0dfff Accounts arm64  
0x18b200000 - 0x18b28ffff VideoToolbox arm64  <59e3d13a5d243b44abf10a5c4ba313f4> /System/Library/Frameworks/VideoToolbox.framework/VideoToolbox
0x18b290000 - 0x18b290fff FontServices arm64  <5a9fc52851583aac96b6745cf7aae370> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/FontServices.framework/FontServices
0x18b291000 - 0x18b3ddfff CoreText arm64  <851f6498f833335fb35ec9e67515c2fb> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreText.framework/CoreText
0x18b3de000 - 0x18b3f8fff ProtocolBuffer arm64  <a3544981c8743eea875d5b7c7bc5b19b> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/ProtocolBuffer.framework/ProtocolBuffer
0x18b3f9000 - 0x18b421fff PersistentConnection arm64  <4a392539b9c33a47b69439638cfaac04> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/PersistentConnection.framework/PersistentConnection
0x18b422000 - 0x18b428fff DataMigration arm64  <6cff1ebc13b332e3809b4722048c6ffb> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/DataMigration.framework/DataMigration
0x18b429000 - 0x18b87dfff AudioToolbox arm64  <0505b7dd6a033bf78117a8cd81a1101b> /System/Library/Frameworks/AudioToolbox.framework/AudioToolbox
0x18b87e000 - 0x18ba5bfff QuartzCore arm64  <416a878f23c636fc8d81404ff7dd4fdc> /System/Library/Frameworks/QuartzCore.framework/QuartzCore
0x18ba5c000 - 0x18ba62fff Netrb arm64  <099e2ab3ae8e3a498e0e0a0f17e128a7> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/Netrb.framework/Netrb
0x18ba63000 - 0x18ba73fff libcmph.dylib arm64  <903e25509e37307e99af188ed1272633> /usr/lib/libcmph.dylib
0x18ba74000 - 0x18ba94fff libmis.dylib arm64  <1a116c60b46a3781a68a9c27e9cf2653> /usr/lib/libmis.dylib
0x18ba95000 - 0x18bb86fff LanguageModeling arm64  <c49bcbbac36d34308151388e8bf1a718> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/LanguageModeling.framework/LanguageModeling
0x18bb87000 - 0x18bc7dfff ManagedConfiguration arm64  <0e15a8564caf3d47ab9b199770bf5cd2> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/ManagedConfiguration.framework/ManagedConfiguration
0x18bc7e000 - 0x18bc94fff libmarisa.dylib arm64  <96c399295cb13cad829c93b5c29f0661> /usr/lib/libmarisa.dylib
0x18bc95000 - 0x18bd65fff ProofReader arm64  <bb56e538be8835199a0abd263adb75f8> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/ProofReader.framework/ProofReader
0x18bd66000 - 0x18bd70fff MediaAccessibility arm64  <17fe4943f5363a278cf9868db2623b9d> /System/Library/Frameworks/MediaAccessibility.framework/MediaAccessibility
0x18bd71000 - 0x18bd81fff MobileAsset arm64  <2a3a006162af37b79c3a6b2ab71344c6> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MobileAsset.framework/MobileAsset
0x18bd82000 - 0x18bdf3fff ColorSync arm64  <996fd30495c33a64b17b87797c54aec2> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/ColorSync.framework/ColorSync
0x18bdf4000 - 0x18be64fff MetalPerformanceShaders arm64  <e78463e7ed8334909ae0968c5b4ddcbc> /System/Library/Frameworks/MetalPerformanceShaders.framework/MetalPerformanceShaders
0x18be65000 - 0x18c294fff FaceCore arm64  <0179b0a45e4932e5967336ac40c0c4d8> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/FaceCore.framework/FaceCore
0x18c312000 - 0x18c4dbfff CoreImage arm64  <8c5c510a2d90361696f6a965b6b933a0> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreImage.framework/CoreImage
0x18c4dc000 - 0x18c52bfff TextInput arm64  <a1a56e91cb0534e8815a23fb6993b023> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/TextInput.framework/TextInput
0x18c52c000 - 0x18c53cfff libAccessibility.dylib arm64  <fbd694050c503c12a3e0e7dfb490b9df> /usr/lib/libAccessibility.dylib
0x18c54c000 - 0x18cf8efff JavaScriptCore arm64  <f4afe098cd9b33c2b3369773851e26b9> /System/Library/Frameworks/JavaScriptCore.framework/JavaScriptCore
0x18d1e1000 - 0x18e3d6fff WebCore arm64  <d0a2b6b3b79434a08272968e20cd00a7> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/WebCore.framework/WebCore
0x18e3d7000 - 0x18e3fffff libxslt.1.dylib arm64  <3edbcb1d6e1d33519db363daf35cfe1c> /usr/lib/libxslt.1.dylib
0x18e400000 - 0x18e56cfff WebKitLegacy arm64  <a7feeddf725930858e5fe93e4e047bb5> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/WebKitLegacy.framework/WebKitLegacy
0x18e56d000 - 0x18e632fff CoreUI arm64  <0a25c84cf6183efead20a5cea30b98ad> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CoreUI.framework/CoreUI
0x18e633000 - 0x18e65afff DictionaryServices arm64  <dd7a3952ff63333ebe91d7eff8347628> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/DictionaryServices.framework/DictionaryServices
0x18e65b000 - 0x18e65efff HangTracer arm64  <13e35bff690836b7b717f3f5ff690897> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/HangTracer.framework/HangTracer
0x18e65f000 - 0x18e6b3fff PhysicsKit arm64  <e53aecfb95ec3252986a82a83a3cafd1> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/PhysicsKit.framework/PhysicsKit
0x18e6b4000 - 0x18e78bfff UIFoundation arm64  <db0623abf2243a578bd1e457f6877483> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/UIFoundation.framework/UIFoundation
0x18e798000 - 0x18f53ffff UIKit arm64  <4ad90348edcc3d21983f83490705f2aa> /System/Library/Frameworks/UIKit.framework/UIKit
0x18f540000 - 0x18f568fff CoreBluetooth arm64  <ced176702d7c37e6a9027eeb3fbf7f66> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreBluetooth.framework/CoreBluetooth
0x18f569000 - 0x18f591fff DataAccessExpress arm64  <6c35e310019e35a38adba222a251f4fc> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/DataAccessExpress.framework/DataAccessExpress
0x18f5b3000 - 0x18f63cfff AddressBook arm64  <6ac637105605370a8cf1bf73e72447bf> /System/Library/Frameworks/AddressBook.framework/AddressBook
0x18f79e000 - 0x18f7c8fff CacheDelete arm64  <b7d03ec01fa83f0c8c876884fb6a7b2a> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CacheDelete.framework/CacheDelete
0x18fef1000 - 0x18ff00fff IntlPreferences arm64  <09d66fe143483a389cd6f502e13da940> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/IntlPreferences.framework/IntlPreferences
0x18ff01000 - 0x18ff03fff CoreDuetDebugLogging arm64  <7e3ea6bf9d463951866292d973db6e6b> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CoreDuetDebugLogging.framework/CoreDuetDebugLogging
0x18ff04000 - 0x18ff18fff CoreDuetDaemonProtocol arm64  
0x1910c8000 - 0x19117bfff Contacts arm64  /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AppleIDAuthSupport.framework/AppleIDAuthSupport
0x1a202e000 - 0x1a21fdfff libFosl_dynamic.dylib arm64  <8e1668637c423351a9b8f75d3db4e1bd> /usr/lib/libFosl_dynamic.dylib
0x1a2619000 - 0x1a264bfff libpcap.A.dylib arm64  <5b50b83d66ba3127ab8bfb9d7773aeab> /usr/lib/libpcap.A.dylib
0x1a2757000 - 0x1a2760fff ProactiveEventTracker arm64  <66b41160346f344b8b7685ea37bf7d3f> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/ProactiveEventTracker.framework/ProactiveEventTracker
0x1a2761000 - 0x1a28f7fff Intents arm64  <c55c244eff3a3b568972131160de46a0> /System/Library/Frameworks/Intents.framework/Intents
0x1a2a38000 - 0x1a2a5bfff UserNotifications arm64  <dea565113b183df0a2d4cd6a375f3142> /System/Library/Frameworks/UserNotifications.framework/UserNotifications
0x1a2a6e000 - 0x1a2a7cfff PersonaKit arm64  <dffe49e16fb6322e98e7a30d94e46c85> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/PersonaKit.framework/PersonaKit
0x1a2f2e000 - 0x1a2fd1fff TextureIO arm64  <a427c8b881e43dad8d3c812bc418d731> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/TextureIO.framework/TextureIO
0x1a44a5000 - 0x1a44b7fff libBNNS.dylib arm64  <7b15b1fd47de37cc94234f1279febec2> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/libBNNS.dylib
0x1a44b8000 - 0x1a44bcfff libQuadrature.dylib arm64  <6142532815973d5f9292892fb7c2c353> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/libQuadrature.dylib
0x1a4916000 - 0x1a4927fff CoreEmoji arm64  <02de2177a2a83b389b2d8796f9576d41> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CoreEmoji.framework/CoreEmoji
0x1a4e56000 - 0x1a4e56fff IntentsFoundation arm64  <640a622a48173a91829abcded6d8ac51> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/IntentsFoundation.framework/IntentsFoundation
0x1a4f9e000 - 0x1a506afff NLP arm64  <9162fa12a5ab3325a413c57dad3dce48> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/NLP.framework/NLP
0x1a5b1d000 - 0x1a5b22fff SymptomDiagnosticReporter arm64  <23b4b5547e8433289e9fc4757ae5eb17> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/SymptomDiagnosticReporter.framework/SymptomDiagnosticReporter
0x1a62e3000 - 0x1a635bfff libate.dylib arm64  <8f60d460abd031edaf8477a229c4006c> /usr/lib/libate.dylib
0x1a635c000 - 0x1a635cfff libcoretls.dylib arm64  <852a1f8d67063962b6699bd608ee1eef> /usr/lib/libcoretls.dylib
0x1a635d000 - 0x1a635efff libcoretls_cfhelpers.dylib arm64  <85a72486fa0e376f8b14a6d19375a1b6> /usr/lib/libcoretls_cfhelpers.dylib
```

Comment: Connect the device to a mac and grab your app logs from Xcode -> Windows -> Devices -> Logs. With that in hands update your original post. It's hard to know what might be happening.

Comment: One hint: check all your permissions are in order, that means you are requesting all your permissions and they are not empty text.

Comment: Can you show your LoginPage code?

Answer (score 1):

I was able to get the solution to the issue. Its good to check the device log as it gives much more information than the crash log.

The issue was some AOT module was not being loaded in the project. So I cleaned the solution ND THEN rebuild my project. All the references in the project was updated.